# PHPUnit 3.6 PHP 5.2.7 PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 16

Tags: php, linux, phpunit, centos5

In our Development server, we have php 5.2 installed. I was asked to install phpunit on it.     I followed the instruction on phpunit site as below:
http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/installation.html

> Note
>
> PHPUnit 3.6 requires PHP 5.2.7 (or later) but PHP 5.3.9 (or later) is
>   highly recommended. PHP_CodeCoverage, the library that is used by
>   PHPUnit to collect and process code coverage information, depends on
>   Xdebug 2.0.5 (or later) but Xdebug 2.1.3 (or later) is highly
>   recommended.
>
> The following two commands (which you may have to run as root) are all
>   that is required to install PHPUnit using the PEAR Installer:
>
> pear config-set auto_discover 1
>
> pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

But there is error when i run phpunit command after installation:

```
[root@dev ~]# phpunit



PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 16
```

I have tested it on fresh Centos 5 installation as well but all is useless. I am fed up of phpunit. Please suggest what to do.

I have manually uninstalled and installed as below:

> First you need to uninstall PHPUnit 3.6 and all of it’s dependencies.
>
> ```
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/DbUnit
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/File_Iterator
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/Text_Template
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_Timer
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
> sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
> sudo pear uninstall pear.symfony-project.com/YAML
> ```
>
> Next install these specific versions of each dependency, in this order, installing PHPUnit-3.5.15 last.
>
> ```
> sudo pear install pear.symfony-project.com/YAML-1.0.2
> sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.1
> sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.3
> sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_Timer-1.0.0
> sudo pear install phpunit/File_Iterator-1.2.3
> sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.2
> sudo pear install phpunit/Text_Template-1.0.0
> sudo pear install phpunit/DbUnit-1.0.0
> sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15
> ```

From the site: http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

The error is same as

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 16
```

Please suggest any ideas to solve this.

Comment: Face the fact that you should upgrade your PHP to at least version 5.3, best to the recent 5.5. You will get performance improvements for free, will be able to run the package manager Composer (more and more software uses it), and avoid being unable to install PHPUnit next year because PEAR support will be removed.

Comment: @Sven all our office projects are working on php 5.2 so this is not possible to upgrade quickly. At the moment I have to find a work around in the current situation.

Comment: PHP 5.3 is pretty backwards compatible, with barely any need to tweak a thing (but there are tools to find out about it, like here: http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2010/06/24/automated-php-5-3-compatibility-testing-for-your-old-code/ ). Chances are you are already compatible and just need to switch the PHP. And if you don't start upgrading soon, the pain will increase more and more.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed and glad to share the answer back.

ISSUE CAUSE:

The issue was that I was following some procedure which was not supported to php 5.2. The link of that document is as below:

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html

I used pear to uninstall PHPUnit which did not uninstall it properly and the binary was left in the system.

SOLUTION:

For php 5.2 we require to install phpunit 3.6 from:
http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/installation.html

Even then When phpunit command was executed, it shown the below mentioned result.

[root@localhost]# phpunit
-bash: /usr/local/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory

We need to Remove the binary left at /usr/local/bin/phpunit because pear installed the binary at:
/usr/bin/phpunit

The solution was to run phpunit through: /usr/bin/phpunit or copy the binary to /usr/local/bin/phpunit

cp /usr/bin/phpunit /usr/local/bin/