# Which version of PHPUnit is suitable to test code PHP version 5.5.9?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have to test php code version 5.5.9 with PHPUnit. Which version is suitable for this purpose?

I'm using PHPUnit 4.8, that require PHP 5.3, and get the following error for a test:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/foo/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:0
PHP   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main($exit = *uninitialized*)
```

According to this Q/A [PHPUnit 3.6 PHP 5.2.7 PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289840/phpunit-3-6-php-5-2-7-php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function-expe)
PHPUnit version cause the error.

I read here https://phpunit.de/manual/5.0/en/installation.html that PHPUnit version 5.0 require PHP 5.6 (so not a good choice for my case).

Which version of PHPUnit should I install to avoid this error?

**UPDATE:** the error does not arise since I added this line in composer.json :

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Note: "why on earth you are not working on php7" is not an answer... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the information you are looking for [here](https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html).